# HTTP Response Generator using Falcon Python and Gunicorn

Tags: python, wsgi, falconframework

I'm trying to write an API for my Python app using Falcon WSGI Framework. Usually, my code goes like this:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Main'

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        data = urlparse.parse_qs(req.stream.read())
        x = data['x'][0]
        y = data['y'][0]
        z = data['z'][0]
        result = main(x,y,z)
        resp.body = json.dumps(result)

    def main(x,y,z):
        sum=x+y+z
        return sum

api = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])
api.add_route('/', Main())
```

In such case, I can return only a single response. However, I want to display additional info like console output in a Linux shell like view.

For this purpose, I would change my main method as given below.

```
    def main(x,y,z):
        yield "X: " + str(x)+"\n"
        yield "Y: " + str(y)+"\n"
        yield "Z: " + str(z)+"\n"
        sum=x+y+z
        yield "SUM: " + str(sum)+"\n"
```

But resp.body in `on_post` method above would return just one value. How can I display my desired data in a console output stream like manner?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried playing around and modifying the `on_post` method as given below worked for me.

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    data = urlparse.parse_qs(req.stream.read())
    x = data['x'][0]
    y = data['y'][0]
    z = data['z'][0]
    resp.stream = main(x,y,z)
```